# What is the benefit of embedding Power BI in edit mode?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

What is the benefit of embedding Power BI in edit mode?

I can see why someone want to embed a report in view mode; to show to some other people. But why in edit mode? Why just not do directly to powerbi.com?

Probably there is a case for it, but I cant figure out why.
The API has some features to enable/disable settings and to switch between view/edit mode: `report.switchMode('edit')` or `report.switchMode('view')`.

So if someone wants to edit a report, is it just more convenient to go to powerbi.com, instead of editing an embed powerbi report?

Answer (score 0):

Edit mode is beneficial when:

1. You want other users to play around with the visuals and data in your embedded report. Suppose user wants to see some changes by editing the visuals, he can do that in edit mode in the embedded report only, instead of going back to powerbi.com. It will be easy and more convenient for the user to do that.
2. Changes done by user are temporary and will not be saved. So if you want that your report visuals or data should not change you can use edit mode.

Find the code snippet for edit mode below:

```js
report.switchMode("edit");
```

Please find reference here- https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#open-in-edit-mode